# Spring cloud data flow UI not showing stream definition for deployed streams

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

In spring-cloud-data-flow UI, after clicking on deployed stream name, stream definition is not visible on UI. It keeps loading but never get loaded. However, whenever somebody clicks on undeployed stream name, definition gets populated on UI.

I searched on google for the error mentioned in the logs but didn't get any related info. It will be great if someone can guide on this issue.

Spring cloud data flow version : 2.0.1

Logs are as below :

`2022-03-23 20:23:36.357 ERROR 7380 --- [http-nio-9393-exec-3] o.s.c.d.s.c.RestControllerAdvice         : Caught exception while handling a request`

`org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404`
`at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:85)`
`at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122)`
`at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102)`
`at org.springframework.cloud.skipper.client.SkipperClientResponseErrorHandler.handleError(SkipperClientResponseErrorHandler.java:78)`
`at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)`
`at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:778)`
`at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:736)`
`at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:691)`
`at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:618)`
`at org.springframework.cloud.skipper.client.DefaultSkipperClient.getLog(DefaultSkipperClient.java:169)`
`at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.stream.SkipperStreamDeployer.getLog(SkipperStreamDeployer.java:498)`
`at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.controller.StreamLogsController.getLog(StreamLogsController.java:50)`
`at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)`
`at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)`
`at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)`
`at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)`
`at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)`
`at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)`
`at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)`
`at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)`
`at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)`
`at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)`
`at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)`
`at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)`
`at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)`
`at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)`
`at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)`
`at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)`
`at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)`
`at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)`
`at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)`
`at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)`
`at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)`
`at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)`
`at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)`
`at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)`
`at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)`
`at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)`
`at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)`
`at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)`
`at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)`
`at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)`
`at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)`
`at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)`
`at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)`
`at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)`
`at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)`
`at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)`
`at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)`
`at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)`
`at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)`
`at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)`
`at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)`
`at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)`
`at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)`
`at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)`
`at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Is the included stacktrace generated when clicking on the deployed or undeployed stream? Does this happen always or is it intermittent? Your best bet may be to open an issue in https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues.

Do the skipper logs have any details in them about that error?

Comment: This stacktrace generates when clicked on deployed stream.
Nothing gets logged into the file when clicked on undeployed stream. This happens always.